# A way to get an image from an url in PlayN

Tags: java, playn

I'm making a game that's part of a service where users can register avatars. 
The problem is that the playn api doesn't seems to have any **load image from URL** function (or maybe I'm kinda blind).

Am I missing some important part of the API??? Wasn't supposed this function to be in `PlayN.graphics()`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After talking with one of the PlayN authors, I discovered that this function exists in the current 1.5-SNAPSHOT version of PlayN (but not in the current 1.4 release). It's called PlayN.assets().getRemoteImage(String url) 
The current Google Code repository is *out of date* (it is merged from times to times by Michael) so you need to build the snapshot from this repo -> https://github.com/threerings/playn